# Change Compressed Python File to Executable

Tags: python, compression, exe, executable

I have a "game" that I made using python and pygame. This "game" has other included files that are miscellaneous text and other files. If I saved this as a .zip file, is there a way to change it into a .exe file? If I do so, can people who don't have python installed on their computer open and use it? How would I make it so that the .exe file would only open the python file but still see and read and write data to the others?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to convert zip to exe and just run it without having its dependencies stored in the path.

You could use something like https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

You can specify the media files that has to be added and the main script to be converted to .exe. All dependencies can be stored in a single folder along with the .exe.